# resize the jqgrid width while browser resizing

Tags: onresize

Hi i have a problem in my jqgrid when i am clicking the pane the grid size is not resizing .how to resize it ?.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but this should keep your grid at 100% width:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    $("#jqgrid").setGridWidth($(window).width());
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: This only works when I refresh the page?  also, is #jqgrid your table element?

Comment: the resize event is triggered any time the browser's width changes, it is not triggered when the browser is loaded (hence the manual trigger of the resize event at the end there). Yes, #jqgrid would be the table element.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer was good, but this solves both problems.
Resizing now and Resizing when the window or IFrame gets resized.

```
        // Size me now...
        $("#list1").setGridWidth($(window).width());

        // Size me later...
        $(window).bind('resize', function () {
            $("#list1").setGridWidth($(window).width());
        }).trigger('resize');
```

Happy coding!